# How to repair a pot with rusted screw on handle

Tags: cookware

Expanding on [How to reattach handles on 30 year old pots?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/82490/how-to-reattach-handles-on-30-year-old-pots), I have a specific example. This pot has a screw-on handle that has rusted over time. I guess this is common since it is easy to get water in it that doesn't dry easily.

[image]
[image]

At this point the handle cannot be removed with a screwdriver. It occurred to me to try WD-40 but not being food safe I am not confident enough to try it.

So I would like to know if someone has had some experience in this kind of situation. I particularly like this pot because it is heavy gauge, non-stick and has 1 cup marks on the inside.

Comment: How is this related to cooking ? [Screw extractor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Screw_extractor)

Comment: @roetnig I imagine chefs and cooking enthusiasts repair a lot of cookware, right? My query at this point is my comment on an answer from Joe, "So I wonder what the screw is affixed to, and if that piece is welded to the pot, or something else." I'd rather not find out the hard way and ruin the pot as it is still usable.

Comment: The answer on how to extract a stubborn or damaged screw is exactly this: screw extractor. Maybe you wanted a fancy answer as "boil water with some salt and pepper for 20 minutes and the screw will be tender and juicy." ;)

Answer (score 1):

If the screw doesn't go all the way through to the inside of the pot, there is no issue with using WD-40. It should help, but that screw is so far stripped that it might still be difficult to remove

Standard practice is to either use screw extractor bits (drill out the head slightly, then use the bit to grab on so you can work it free) or to cut a slot in it, so that you can use a standard screwdriver (if it were exposed, you just need a hacksaw.. with that you'd need a dremel or needle files to cut the slot)

It's also worth making sure that you're using the correct type and size of bits when removing screws.  Too small of a philips bit can strip the head of the screw.  Also learn to identify positive (used in Europe, e.g. IKEA furniture), while philips is mostly US.

Comment: I have plenty of experience tapping out screws, and I agree it does not go into the pot itself. So I wonder what the screw is affixed to, and if that piece is welded to the pot, or something else.

Answer (score 0):

This is more of a [Lifehacks](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com) question than a Seasoned Advice one, but you can always drill out the screw, tap new threads in the hole and re-attach the same handle with a bigger screw, or just drill through-and-through and re-attach with a nut and bolt.

Answer (score 0):

Normally 10 w 40 for about a week. Tap with a hammer 1 time a day for vibration to move oil down threads. Try again to remove. No? Next step take to the area bike shop or such. Have him cut a grove in screw head & remove with regular screw driver. Takes a mototoll for this.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that manufacturers such as Tefal use ordinary steel screws which rust easily when they get wet during washing up, especially if they are screwed into aluminium.  The answer is to use a stainless steel screw.  If you *do* manage to get the old screw loose, I suggest you replace it with a stainless steel one!  Also, clean up the thread in the socket with the correct size of tap if you can, & smear some food-safe silicone grease on the threads so it never seizes up again.